# How to get most similar Eigenfaces or Fisherfaces in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, similarity, face-recognition

I'm trying to find a measurement for the similarity of 2 faces. I use OpenCV. For that I train Eigenfaces / Fisherfaces with 1000 Photos of 1000 different people (so 1 Photo each person). So I also have 1000 labels in the training set.

Now I can use the predict method to get the most similar face.

I want to input 2 unknown face images to find if they are both similar to the same vector of faces in the training set.

Here is the code of openCV that returns the most similar label (with the lowest distance).

```
for(size_t sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < _projections.size(); sampleIdx++) {
    double dist = norm(_projections[sampleIdx], q, NORM_L2);
    if((dist < minDist) && (dist < _threshold)) {
        minDist = dist;
        minClass = _labels.at<int>((int)sampleIdx);
    }
```

Questions:

1. Can anyone tell me how to rewrite this to output the top 10 faces and not just the top 1 ? I'm thinking about pushing them into a priority queue, but maybe there is something easier?!
2. In the training: should I put all the faces on the same label or on different labels? So should I have 1 label or 1000 ?

Cheers

Comment: :: Q2 :Different label for different subject/person. So, 1000 labels is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did. Note I'm really good at perl, really newb at C++ (in fact, this is my first c++ project!) so I output a lot to the command line and parsed it with perl.

I went to facerec.cpp as you did, and I changed the contents of the for loop to this:

```
for(size_t sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < _projections.size(); sampleIdx++) {
    double dist = norm(_projections[sampleIdx], q, NORM_L2);
    int labelClass = _labels.at<int>((int)sampleIdx);
    cout << dist << " " << labelClass << endl;
    if((dist < minDist) && (dist < _threshold)) {
        minDist = dist;
        minClass = _labels.at<int>((int)sampleIdx);
    }
}
```

This now outputs the distance and label of every face. Since all the predict function appears to do is take the picture with the shortest distance (lowest number) and return that as the answer, you can now take the resulting list, sort it, and take the first 10 results. Or you can take the first ten labels or whatever. This just gives you access to all of the data rather than the first X results.

I also added

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

to the top of the file so I could use cout.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:: Since OpenCV doesn't provide a default function, you have to create your own by creating a vector which has distance and label. You can write your own function as below and store the distance and label in the vector. Here you need to rebuild the opencv.

```
virtual void predict(InputArray src, int &label, double &confidence,  Vector <variable>) const = 0;
```